# Working with xib and viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have one button in .xib file.

I want that if I will click on that button .xib file color of viewController should be changed.

How can I do that?

Should I use NSNotification or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: load the xib using loadnibname and the add the view as subview to your view controller and the set the target action for the button :) write the method in your view controller finally change the color using [self.view setBackgroundColor:"your color"] thats all :)

Comment: target action for the button will be in .xib's swift file.. not in its view controller. am I right?

Comment: may I know why do you have a button in seperate xib ?? Why dont you place it in your viewController's xib itself ??? Code will be much easier to deal with isn't it :)

Comment: actually I have color pelete in my .xib. In my viewController I have to load so  many different view. That's why I thought to use .xib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your `UIButton` on xib with an `IBAction` within your class inherited from `UIViewController` and change the `view` property of `UIViewController`. You can do it using `self.view.backgroundColor`

Here is simple code snippet to do that. Hope it helps.

```
@IBAction func myButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() //Or any color of your choice 
}
```

Comment: Can I connect .xib's button to it's viewController class? @khunshan

Comment: Yes. If you have set the name of UIViewController inherited class in your xib -> Identity Inspector (on right panel) -> Class. You need to create an IBAction in code and connect it with UIButton from your xib file.

Answer (score 5):

A `UIViewController` doesn't have a color. You might be talking about its root view, maybe `tintColor` from a `UINavigationBar` if it's embedded in a `UINavigationController`?

In any case, a `IBAction` connected to your `UIButton` will do what you want.

Comment: You can always set the self.view.backgroundColor :) and viewcontroller's color will be changed :P Every viewcontroller has a view inside it isn't it :P

Comment: @SandeepBhandari This is wrong and misleading. The `UIViewController` is not changing any color, it's its root `UIView` that is changing, don't spread wrong information please.

Comment: I believe I said the same thing :P self.view.backgroundColor means you are changing the root view of UIViewController :) There was nothing misleading :)

Comment: Quoting you `viewcontroller's color will be changed`. **This is wrong**. So no you didn't say the same thing.